# Group rows by level and put name for each

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table

```
id   ins  sec  div  subject  subjectHour  level
1     1    1    7   subName       5      level 1
2     1    2    7   subName2      4      level 1
3     1    2    7   subName3      4      level 2
4     1    1    7   subName4      6      level 2
```

I want to out put something like

level 1 subjects 
subName
subName2

level 2 subjects
subName3
subName4

mysql JOIN the 4 tables

```
    $displayMat = $db->prepare('SELECT
     a.id, a.ins_id, a.sub_name, a.subHour, a.level,
     b.id, b.ins_name,
     c.id, sec_name,
     d.id, div_name
     FROM ins_subjects AS a
     INNER JOIN institutes AS b
     INNER JOIN ins_sections AS c
     INNER JOIN ins_division AS d
     WHERE a.ins_id=?
     GROUP BY a.id;
 ');
```

and here is the looping

```
$displayMat->bind_param('i', $inId);
  if ($displayMat->execute()) {
  $results = $displayMat->get_result();
  while ($m = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
<li>
  <div class="col-xs-3"><?php print $m['sub_name']; ?></div>
  <div class="col-xs-3"><?php print $m['ins_name']; ?></div>
  <div class="col-xs-3"><?php print $m['sec_name']; ?></div>
  <div class="col-xs-3"><?php print $m['div_name']; ?></div>
</li>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You SQL needs some join conditions, and the GROUP BY seem superfluous.

Starting with something like this:-

```
SELECT a.id, a.ins_id, a.sub_name, a.subHour, a.level,
        b.id, b.ins_name,
        c.id, sec_name,
        d.id, div_name
FROM ins_subjects AS a
INNER JOIN institutes AS b ON a.ins_id = b.id
INNER JOIN ins_sections AS c ON a.sec_id = c.id
INNER JOIN ins_division AS d ON a.div_id = d.id
ORDER BY a.level, a.sub_name
```

you can read each row in turn. Store the level and when the level changes from the previous row you output the level.

EDIT

Crudely done in php, something like this (not used lists here)

```
<?php
$displayMat->bind_param('i', $inId);
if ($displayMat->execute()) 
{
    $results = $displayMat->get_result();
    $prev_level = '';
    while ($m = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) 
    {
        if ($prev_level != $m['level'])
        {
            echo $m['level'];
        }
        $prev_level = $m['level'];
        ?>
          <div class="col-xs-3"><?php print $m['sub_name']; ?></div>
          <div class="col-xs-3"><?php print $m['ins_name']; ?></div>
          <div class="col-xs-3"><?php print $m['sec_name']; ?></div>
          <div class="col-xs-3"><?php print $m['div_name']; ?></div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to code that in php really. I will add some code.

Comment: thanks for the editing yes I am sorry I didn't get the last line on your answer "you can read each row in turn. Store the level and when the level changes from the previous row you output the level."

Comment: I think I almost there but `$prev_level = $m['level'];` will display all the levels like `level 1, level 2, level 3, level 5` and then the subjects will come under them, but What I need is to make the `level` and the related subjects under it like `level 1` subjects `blah, blah` and `level 2` subjects `blah, blah`

Comment: No, the query brings back all the details (ie, just one query, no need for a 2nd query). That bit checks if the level name is the same as the one previously output and if not it outputs it. If it is the same then it doesn't output it.

Comment: what happened is all the levels displays on one line and then all the subjects in one line, I need to out put the `level` and then the related subjects under this level, that what I mean

Comment: The code doesn't do that. Check the source that is put out (ie, it could be your browser moving things around due to divs or lists). You might need to set up an unordered list with each level being a list item which itself has an unordered list of subjects below it for that level.